# How to reference an instance method in constructor invocation

Tags: generics, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am writing some coroutines based event handling code in Kotlin and it's going great.  I have code in various events handlers that does the same thing and I am trying to put this code in one place.  I am stuck on the following.  The idea is that subclasses can specify which event types the can handle by providing a map of classes to methods.  I can't get it to compile though.  Is there a way to make this work?  Is there a better way of doing it?  Thanks.

```
abstract class EventHandler(private val handlers: Map<KClass<out Event>, suspend (Event) -> Unit>) {
    suspend fun handle(event: Event) {
        val handler = handlers[event::class]
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(event)
        } else {
            throw IllegalStateException("No handler configured for $event")
        }
    }
}

data class ExampleEvent(private val id: String): Event

class ExampleHandler(): EventHandler(mapOf(ExampleEvent::class to handleExample)) {
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - compile error
    suspend fun handleExample(event: ExampleEvent) {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get it to compile for 3 different reasons:

1. Since `handleExample` is an instance method, you can't refer it in the super constructor since the instance of your subclass isn't created yet.
2. If you want a function reference of an instance method you should prefix it with `::`, so in your case `::handleExample`.
3. The function `handleExample` accepts an event of type `ExampleEvent` so it doesn't conform to the input type `Event`, in this case, you'd need a cast.

That said, there's a solution to your problem which solves the 3 points above and the burden to repeat that boilerplate for each `EventHandler` subclass.

The explanation is all on the comments.

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Event> typedCoroutine(crossinline block: suspend (T) -> Unit): Pair<KClass<out Event>, suspend (Event) -> Unit> =
    // Since the type is reified, we can access its class.
    // The suspend function calls the required suspend function casting its input.
    // The pair between the two is returned.
    T::class to { event -> block(event as T) }

abstract class EventHandler {
    // Require the subclasses to implement the handlers.
    protected abstract val handlers: Map<KClass<out Event>, suspend (Event) -> Unit>

    suspend fun handle(event: Event) {
        val handler = handlers[event::class]
        if (handler != null) {
            handler(event)
        } else {
            throw IllegalStateException("No handler configured for $event")
        }
    }
}

class ExampleHandler : EventHandler() {
    // The type of typedCoroutine is inferred from handleExample.
    override val handlers: Map<KClass<out Event>, suspend (Event) -> Unit> = mapOf(typedCoroutine(::handleExample))

    suspend fun handleExample(event: ExampleEvent) {
        TODO()
    }
}
```

Using `typedCoroutine` you can fill the `handlers` map easily in all your `EventHandler` subclasses.

Comment: This is great!  It works perfectly.  Is there any way I can simply the declaration of the subclasses so they just list their methods?  So instead of mapOf(typedCoroutine(::handleExample), typedCoroutine(::handleExample2)) I would just declare listOf(::handleExample, ::handleExample2) ?

Comment: @B255 Unfortunately no, there's no way to do that because creating a list, you'd lose the `reified T` needed to create the internal map. The thing I said is just a simplification since you can theoretically list the methods and have still the type BUT it would be the base type of all the inputs of those methods, which isn't useful in your case.